# How to combine two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python

How would I combine these two with python ?

```
d1 = [{a:1, b:2},{a:2,b:5}]
d2 = [{s:3, f:1},{s:4, f:9}]
```

I would just like to add d2 to the end if d1, so:

```
d2 = [{a:1, b:2},{a:2,b:5},{s:3, f:1},{s:4, f:9}]
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer to your question is dict.extend() (as pointed by *Ant*). However your example concerns list concatenation, not dictionary extension.

So, if both arguments are lists you can concatenate them as in:

```
> d1 + d2
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'s': 3, 'f': 1}, {'s': 4, 'f': 9}]
```

which is equivalent to calling list.extend():

```
L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
```

Answer (score 6):

`d1.extend(d2)` however you're combining two lists not two dictionaries

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it in Python 2.7:

```
combined = {}
combined.update(d1)
combined.update(d2)
```

It is good to define a utility function to do this:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    ''' Merge two dictionaries. '''
    merged = {}
    merged.update(d1)
    merged.update(d2)
    return merged
```

Comment: >>> d1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':2,'b':5}]
>>> d2 = [{'s':3,'f':1},{'s':2,'f':9}]
>>> l3 = {}
>>> l3.update(l1)
>>> l3
{'a': 'b'}
>>> l3.update(l2)
>>> l3
{'a': 'b'}